# Calling variable from fetch response

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, velo, mastercard

I am trying to call a global variable from a third party service's file that I fetched. However, I am unable to do so and have been getting a 'Checkout is not defined' error.

```
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const url = "https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/57/checkout.js"; //
const res = await fetch(proxyurl + url);
const data = await res.text();
console.log(data);

Checkout.configure({
          session: { 
            id: '111111'
            },
          interaction: {
                merchant: {
                    name: 'Your merchant name',
                    address: {
                        line1: '200 Sample St',
                        line2: '1234 Example Town'            
                    }    
                }
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch that script you get it as a sting (plain text) and not as runnable script.
You could manually download that script and upload it as a public/backend script.